# Limit Number of Scheduled Backup

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, backup

I have set up a Scheduled Backup (Database and Media) which works fine.
However, it's done every day and I now have 72 of them!

I only need to keep the last 7 days worth.
Is there any way of deleting the older backups? And is there a way of automatically limiting the number of backups kept?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can survive your files with my custom function.

```
public function deleteBackupFiles() {

        $filelist = array();
        if ($handle = opendir(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . "backups" . DS)) {
            while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
                //if ($this->endsWith($entry, "_db.gz")) {            
                if ($this->endsWith($entry, "nomedia.tgz")) {
                    $filelist[] = $entry;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }

        foreach ($filelist as $each_file) {
            /* echo "<br> $filename was last modified: " . date ("Y-m-d h:i:s", filemtime(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . "backups" . DS.$each_file));

              $last_modi = filemtime(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . "backups" . DS.$each_file); */
            if (time() - filemtime(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . "backups" . DS . $each_file) >= 7 * 86400) { // where 7 is days
                unlink(Mage::getBaseDir("var") . DS . "backups" . DS . $each_file);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

cron tab should look like

```
  <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <your_custom_tag_backup_files>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 4 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>yourmodel/observer::deleteBackupFiles</model>
                </run>
            </your_custom_tag_backup_files> 
          </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Add this function to your custom model / observer and run it with cron expression.

let me know if i could help you more

Comment: Looks great. Don't know what my 'custom model / observer' is, or how to run it with a cron expression.

Comment: @PhilStewart, i have added cron tab just add this to your `config.xml` file so it will delete all back files which is older then 7 days at 4 am

Comment: Great. The cron looks straightforward - but what do I do with the function?

Comment: put it in some model and change yourmodel in cron tab to define model

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... How do I put it in 'some model'?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to write a shell script, like shown here: https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux (just adapt the number of days)

After that, setup a cron job outside of Magento and run it every day. Might also work.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access.

`find var/backups -type f -mtime +14 -delete`

Removes all files older than 14 days from within the backup directory.

You could easily convert it into a script to run as a cronjob outside Magento.